# JPEG file in WEB-INF returned as null by ServletContext#getResource()

Tags: java, servlets

Good day!

I am trying to output a JPG file contained in the web application to the
user using the following code:

```
public class JpegOutput extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        byte bufferArray[] = new byte[1024];
        ServletContext ctxt = getServletContext();

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = ctxt.getResource("/WEB-INF/image/image1.jpg").openStream();
        int read = is.read(bufferArray);
        while (read != 1) {
            os.write(bufferArray);
            read = is.read(bufferArray);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

But an error appears:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
exception java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am not sure if it can't read the source image or something. Anyway, I put the image inside this folder /WEB-INF/image/image1.jpg

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT: I solved the problem by renaming the filename... the file name is case sensitive, instead of `image1.jpg,` it should be `image1.JPG`

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason why this image is not in the public webcontent? Then you don't need a servlet.

Comment: If you want to be a great programmer someday (as stated in your profile), you really have to answer the above comment :) This code smells too much.

Comment: @BalusC I'm just studying the possibilities. I don't plan using it that way. I am just a beginner.. and I've read it in a book so I tried doing the code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` to get the path to `/WEB-INF/`. E.g.

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF/image/image1.jpg";
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Though its not sure that this is the reason for the NPE. Can you check the log file and post the stacktrace?

Comment: `ServletContext.getResource()` doesn't work with classpath, its usage in question is correct.

Comment: True, my mistake, mixed it with Class.getResource().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error, but I think it would be better to forward the request rather than serve the image manually:

```
public class JpegOutput extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/image/image1.jpg")
            .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Also note that you content-serving loop is incorrect, the correct one looks like this:

```
while ((read = is.read(bufferArray)) != -1)
    os.write(bufferArray, 0, read);
```