# Image is not displaying when trying to display it from out of my project (local disk)

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to display image in my jsp from my local disk inside a web project. My Code is:

```
<img src="C:/Documents and Settings/chandhu/HelloWorld0.png" width="80px" height="100px" style="margin-left: 20px;"/>
```

After I run my application the image is not getting displayed. In src attribute it is additionally adding some source as mentioned below:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/Ecm/C:/Documents and Settings/chandhu/HelloWorld0.png" width="80px" height="100px" style="margin-left: 20px;"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: in your project create a folder images and put all the image in that folder. <img src="/images/imagename with ext">

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the reply dude :) yes i can do that but my requirement is not that we need to display it from outside the project folder

Comment: Are You using tomcat by any chance?

Comment: @MauricePerry yes i'm using tomcat

Comment: Well you can't. It's a restriction on the browser side. Older versions of the browsers could access local files, but not any more.

Comment: @MauricePerry is there anyother way.so that i can display it from local disk?

Comment: Unless you run your tomcat on the local machine, there is none.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this way.. It should be in reach of container. or you can write a servlet which will read disk file and make HTTPResponse

Comment: thanks for the reply dude :) can u please give me link for sample example of to read a disk file if possible

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using jsp , therefor i think you are working with web application ,in your WEB-INF folder create a directory named  image or as you needed  and put your image there .

Now you can access that from code as :

```
String fullPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/image/" + image_file_name+ ".jpg");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fullPath );
```

Or you may use :

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/image/image_file_name.jpg");
```

to read stream directly .

related question may help you :

[JPEG file in WEB-INF returned as null by ServletContext#getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144891/jpeg-file-in-web-inf-returned-as-null-by-servletcontextgetresource)

[Cant retrieve an images from the WEB-INF folder ussing classLoader.getResourceAsStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250704/cant-retrieve-an-images-from-the-web-inf-folder-ussing-classloader-getresourceas)

Comment: ican able to display image from my project folder.but i wat it display from outside the folder (i.e.,) local disk drive location.

Comment: outside of your application context i think ?

Comment: my image is in c drive dude i need to display it from c drive

Comment: yes , it is out of application context , then niiraj874u answer will works for you